# Resultative secondary predicate

Tags: syntax, generative-grammar, predicatives

In the sentence 'John entered the room angry', can 'angry' be considered a resultative predicate? This sentence has the same construction as 'John painted the door green', but while 'green' describes the internal argument 'the door', 'angry' describes the external argument 'John', so I am a bit confused.

Comment: How could it be a _resultative_ predicate? A resultative predicate describes the result of some sort of action or process in the sentence – what’s the process here? John’s anger is a state, not the result of anything expressed in the sentence, so while it may be predicative, I don’t see how it can be resultative.

Comment: And then there's _They shot him dead, They buried him alive, They want her dead, They found him dead, They made him mad, They found the film delightful,_ etc. Cf [The Green Conspiracy](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111065/15299)

Answer (score 2):

*John entered the room angry.*

I'd say that "angry" is an optional depictive functioning as a 'predicative adjunct'.

It's an adjunct because it's an optional item functioning here as a modifier in clause structure, and it's predicative because it's related to a predicand, i.e. "John". (Compare the predicative complement in "John was angry".).

Predicative adjuncts are not restricted to AdjPs; they can also be PPs ("*In a bad temper*, as usual, John walked on ahead of the main party") or NPs ("*A proud teetotaller*, John stuck to water while the others drank champagne.").